# How to use mask indexing on numpy arrays of classes?

Tags: python, numpy

When working with numpy `array` of custom classes like:

```
class TestClass:
    active = False
```

How to use the inline masking (boolean index arrays) like described here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays

Direct attempt fails:

```
items = np.array([TestClass() for _ in range(10)])
items[items.active]

  AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'active'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your array is `dtype=object` (print it) and each element points to an instance of your class:

```
items = np.array([TestClass() for _ in range(10)])
```

Now try:

```
items.active
```

`items` is an array; `active` is an attribute of your class, not an attribute of the array of your objects.  Your definition does not add any functionality to the class `ndarray`.  The error isn't in the masking; it's in trying to get the instance attribute.

Many operations on arrays like this have be done iteratively.  This kind of array is similar to a plain Python list.

```
[obj.active for obj in items]
```

or to turn it back into an array

```
np.array([obj...])
```

`items[[True,False,True,...]]` should work, but that's because the mask is a boolean list or array already.

====================

Lets modify your class so it shows something interesting.  Note I am assigning `active` to instances, not, as you did, to the class:

```
In [1671]: class TestClass:
      ...:     def __init__(self,val):
      ...:        self.active = bool(val%2)

In [1672]: items = np.array([TestClass(i) for i in range(10)])

In [1674]: items
Out[1674]: 
array([<__main__.TestClass object at 0xb106758c>,
       <__main__.TestClass object at 0xb117764c>,
       ...
       <__main__.TestClass object at 0xb269850c>], dtype=object)
# print of the array isn't interesting.  The class needs a `__str__` method.
```

This simple iterative access to the attribute:

```
In [1675]: [i.active for i in items]
Out[1675]: [False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True]
```

`np.frompyfunc` provides a more powerful way of accessing each element of an array.  `operator.attrgetter('active')(i)` is a functional way of doing `i.active`.

```
In [1676]: f=np.frompyfunc(operator.attrgetter('active'),1,1)
In [1677]: f(items)
Out[1677]: array([False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True], dtype=object)
```

but the main advantage of this function appears when I change the shape of the array:

```
In [1678]: f(items.reshape(2,5))
Out[1678]: 
array([[False, True, False, True, False],
       [True, False, True, False, True]], dtype=object)
```

Note this array is dtype object.  That's what `frompyfunc` does.  To get an array of booleans we need to change type:

```
In [1679]: f(items.reshape(2,5)).astype(bool)
Out[1679]: 
array([[False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

`np.vectorize` uses `frompyfunc`, and makes the dtype a little more user friendly.  But in timings it's a bit slower.

===============

Expanding on Jon's comment

```
In [1702]: class TestClass:
      ...:     def __init__(self,val):
      ...:        self.active = bool(val%2)
      ...:     def __bool__(self):
      ...:         return self.active
      ...:     def __str__(self):
      ...:         return 'TestClass(%s)'%self.active
      ...:     def __repr__(self):
      ...:         return str(self)

In [1707]: items = np.array([TestClass(i) for i in range(5)])
```

`items` now display in an informative manner; and convert to strings:

```
In [1708]: items
Out[1708]: 
array([TestClass(False), TestClass(True), TestClass(False),
       TestClass(True), TestClass(False)], dtype=object)
In [1709]: items.astype('S20')
Out[1709]: 
array([b'TestClass(False)', b'TestClass(True)', b'TestClass(False)',
       b'TestClass(True)', b'TestClass(False)'], 
      dtype='|S20')
```

and convert to `bool`:

```
In [1710]: items.astype(bool)
Out[1710]: array([False,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

In effect `astype` is applying the conversion method to each element of the array.  We could also define `__int__`, `__add__`, This shows that it is easier to add functionality to the custom class than to the array class itself.  I wouldn't expect to get the same speed as with native types.

Comment: How about `def __bool__(self): return self.active` - that seems to behave itself in obvious cases... Well... for `astype(bool)` anyway...

Comment: Yes that does work; `items.astype(bool)` returns that same array.  Array methods like this work on object arrays if the objects themselves implement the appropriate method.  It's easier to add functionality to your own class than to the array class.