# How to sum dictionary value in python?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a list get from database.

```
[{
  'name': 'John',
  'score': 30
}, {
  'name': 'Jan',
  'score': 23
}, {
  'name': 'Mike',
  'score': 34
}]
```

Can [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) get the sum of the score? *(without loop through 1 by 1 using `for in`)*

Comment: Is not duplicate, my case is list of dictionary, I just want to add the `score`, and I did mention without loop through 1 by 1. like `numpy.sum(list)`

Comment: ohh..ok got it. retracted!! May i suggest you to update the heading to mention that as well. kinda a misleading. the without loop part is only at the end.

Comment: The title is misleading.  This isn't a column; it's a dictionary value.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by performing a `sum` on a list comprehension that collects all the "scores":

```
sum( [x['score'] for x in MyListOfDictionaries] )
```

(PS. Numpy is not necessary here)

***Edit:*** as pointed out by @sebastian in the comments, the brackets around the list comprehension aren't necessary since we're plugging this directly into a function, i.e.:

```
sum(x['score'] for x in MyListOfDictionaries)
```

this is known as "generator" syntax; from a performance point of view it can be more efficient as it avoids the extra step of allocating memory for the list before processing it.

Comment: There's no need for the outer `[]` brackets though - you can call `sum` on a generator as well, avoiding the creation of a temporary list containing all the scores.

Comment: thanks, good catch. I'm used to julia where you can't omit them so I keep doing this :p I'll update with your comment. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
In [1963]: ll=[{
  ...:   'name': 'John',
  ...:   'score': 30
  ...: }, {
  ...
  ...: }]
```

First the obvious iterative solution

```
In [1965]: sum([d['score'] for d in ll])
Out[1965]: 87
```

I can turn it into an object array with:

```
In [1966]: np.array(ll)
Out[1966]: 
array([{'score': 30, 'name': 'John'}, {'score': 23, 'name': 'Jan'},
       {'score': 34, 'name': 'Mike'}], dtype=object)
```

but applying `sum` directly to that won't help.  But:

```
In [1967]: from operator import itemgetter
In [1970]: np.frompyfunc(itemgetter('score'),1,1)(ll).sum()
Out[1970]: 87
```

See my recent answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38936480/901925 for more on how to access attributes of objects in an array.

`frompyfunc` doesn't really get rid of iteration - it just wraps it in a user friendly manner.  And the `itemgetter` is still doing `item['score']` for each dictionary in the list.

This use of `itemgetter` is basically the same as:

```
In [1974]: list(map(itemgetter('score'), ll))
Out[1974]: [30, 23, 34]
```

List comprehension, map, `frompyfunc` are all ways of iterating through the list and getting the `score` value from each dictionary.

`pandas` may be able to turn this whole list into a dataframe, but don't be fooled by its ease of use - it's doing all of this, and more, under the covers.

Answer (score 1):

`NumPy` is a library for numerical arrays processing. You use numbers as columns names, convert your collection to matrix and use `NumPy` to make your calculations if you want to use exactly `NumPy` and its performance.

I suggest you to try [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library: it has a type [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) which was created to contain and process collections like yours (like dataframes in `R` language or tables in `MatLab`) — tables with columns and rows. It has [sum](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) method which solves your problem.

I guess, it's not the only thing that you want to do with your data and speed is important — I'd recommend to use this library.

Here are related StackOverflow questions, which will show you some abilities of the library:

- [Sum up column values in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20181456/1305036)
- [How do I sum values in a column that match a given condition using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236305)

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [{
  'name': 'John',
  'score': 30
}, {
  'name': 'Jan',
  'score': 23
}, {
  'name': 'Mike',
  'score': 34
}]

sum(map(lambda x: x['score'], lst))
```